# How to define QML gradient object in javascript

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qt-creator, qtquick2

This is my qtquick qml code

```
function show_me(element) {
    console.log(element.gradient)
}


Rectangle {
    gradient: Gradient {
        GradientStop {
            position: 0
            color: "#30cfd0"
        }

        GradientStop {
            position: 1
            color: "#330867"
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true

        onEntered: {
            show_me(parent)
        }
    }
}
```

The output is

```
qml: QQuickGradient(0x559f18a4dd40)
```

the output gives me a QtQuickGradient object

> I wonder how do I define a QtQuickGradient object in javascript?

I want to something like:

```
var gradient = //QtQuickGradient (i don't know)
element.gradient = gradient
```

Please help me to define it

Comment: The [QtQuickGradient](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/src/quick/items/qquickrectangle_p.h#n121) class is private, you cannot create it directly/without tricks. You should do that in QML instead.

Comment: So then How do I change gradient on hover ? Please provide me some reference

Comment: see my answer below

Comment: Thanks folibis really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the `Gradient` object using common `Component` item, for example:

```js
Component {
    id: myGradient
    Gradient {
        GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "red" }
        GradientStop { position: 0.5; color: "yellow" }
        GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "green" }
    }
}

Rectangle {
    id: rect
    width: 100
    height: 100
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    color: "orange"
    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "click me"
    }
    TapHandler {
        onTapped: {
            var gradient = myGradient.createObject(rect);
            rect.gradient = gradient;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks folibis really appreciate your help.